# reactjs error - AJAX Failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: django, reactjs, redux, wagtail

I get the following error on the console for running the reactjs application.

```
   AJAX Failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

on the developer tools console window.  I got the following error.

```
 search-e3e9d0f9da88f042e3cb.js:446 Warning: React attempted to reuse markup in a container but the checksum was invalid. This generally means that you are using server rendering and the markup generated on the server was not what the client was expecting. React injected new markup to compensate which works but you have lost many of the benefits of server rendering. 
 Instead, figure out why the markup being generated is different on the 
 client or server:
 (client) " data-reactid="18">Medium</div><button 
 (server) " data-reactid="18">Large</div><button s
```

It is wagtail application(it is like Django-cms), in which react module is called inside the wagtail application. The development environment is Ubuntu on aws.

Please help me in resolving this issue. I am not able to find the origin of the error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like your JSON is not valid, try [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com)

Comment: Hi Alexander,  What would be the reason for second error.  Please throw some light on it.  With many thanks, Bharath AK

Comment: If you are using react 16 and SSR you should render using ReactDOM.hydrate(), this might be the problem.

Comment: First error is ajax failure.  I had located the code where it is being called.

Comment: Hi Alexander, Thanks for your help.  Now the application is running. First error resolved, port was not assigned on the ajax call i.e why I was getting the error.  I dont why the second error is occuring.  Any way thank you now the application is running.  Thanks Bharath AK

Comment: You should mark question as correct answer or at least up vote.
That way the things work here :-)